# httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback not giving exception when publickey is wrong

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ssl-certificate

I am doing this in Xamarin forms using C#, followed by this sample https://github.com/chrisriesgo/xamarin-cert-pinning/tree/master/PinCerts.

STEP-1

```
public static class SSLValidator
{
    static string PUBLIC_KEY = "MYPUBLICKEY";
    public static void Initialize()
    { 
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = OnValidateCertificate;
    }
    static bool OnValidateCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        var certPublicString = certificate?.GetPublicKeyString();
        var keysMatch = PUBLIC_KEY == certPublicString;
        return keysMatch;
    }
}
```

STEP - 2

Calling this class in App.cs

```
SSLValidator.Initialize();
```

STEP - 3

```
Calling in Android MainActivity OnCreate

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, cert, chain, errors) => true;
```

STEP - 4

```
Finally my RestService Class

    private HttpClient getClient()
    {
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true; 
        }
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.RestBaseUrl)
        };
        return client;
    }
```

Issue: Even though my public key is wrong below code not giving an exception.

```
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true;
```

Comment: You're registering the correct handler, then an "everything works" handler.  Does it work better if you leave off the one where you always return true?  (If you need to register it on an instance, like in Step 4, register the static SSLValidator.OnValidateCertificate)

Comment: you mean to say, explicitly call the SSLValidator.OnValidateCertificate()?. OnValidateCertificate() is a call back method for ServerCertificateValidationCallback.

Comment: Remove `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, cert, chain, errors) => true;` and replace `httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true;` with `httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = SSLValidator.OnValidateCertificate;`